# using sinonjs to test a function that calls new on a dependency

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon, es6-class

I'm terribly confused and would love some help.

I don't think this code is poorly designed, but correct me if you see a flaw.

I can't seem to figure out how to test a function that calls `new` on a dependency.  Here are my boiled down classes....with irrelevant business logic stripped.

MyWrapper.js

```
const SomeLib = require('SomeLib');

module.exports.MyWrapper = class MyWrapper {
    constructor(username, password) {
        this._someLib = new SomeLib(username, password);
    }

    async getFoo(id) {
        // other business logic omitted
        // which was tested in the MyWrapper.spec.js
        return this._someLib.findById(id)
    }

    async saveFoo(object) {
        // other business logic omitted
        // which was tested in the MyWrapper.spec.js
        return this._someLib.save(object)
    }
}
```

MyApp.js

```
const MyWrapper = require('MyWrapper');

const process = async (message) => {
    const wrapper = new MyWrapper(process.env.username, process.env.password)
    // some business logic around the message...omitted
    const data = wrapper.getFoo(message.id);
    if(data) {
       // do stuff with the data
       wrapper.saveFoo(data);
    } else {
       console.log('no data found for message', message);
    }
}
module.exports = { process }
```

MyApp.spec.js

```
const sut = require('MyApp');

describe('MyApp', function(){
    describe('process', function(){
        it('should not call save when no data found', async function(){
             // how do I prevent 'new MyWrapper(process.env.username, process.env.password)' from being called???
             // how do I stub "wrapper.getFoo(message.id)" so I can return "undefined"
             const msg = {......};
             await sut.process(msg);
             // now assert wrapper.getFoo was called
             // now assert wrapper.saveFoo was *NOT* called
        });

        it('should call save when data is found', async function(){
             // how do I prevent 'new MyWrapper(process.env.username, process.env.password)' from being called???
             // how do I stub "wrapper.getFoo(message.id)" so I can return some JSON
             const msg = {......};
             await sut.process(msg);
             // now assert wrapper.getFoo was called
             // now assert wrapper.saveFoo was called
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

from looking at your code with the way it is currently structured, you won't be able to not call `new MyWrapper` because that call is made inside the function that you are calling. What you likely would want to do is use dependency injection to pass in an instance of `MyWrapper`. Using DI would also allow you to pass in a mocked version of your Wrapper class for more control over testing. This would look something like this:

```
// MyApp.js

const MyWrapper = require('MyWrapper');

const wrapper = new MyWrapper(process.env.username, process.env.password);

const process = async (message, wrapper) => {
    // some business logic around the message...omitted
    const data = wrapper.getFoo(message.id);
    if(data) {
       // do stuff with the data
       wrapper.saveFoo(data);
    } else {
       console.log('no data found for message', message);
    }
}
module.exports = { process }
```

You may want to instantiate the wrapper somewhere else that makes sense for your application, but based on the code you have presented this would now allow you to pass in your own test version of the Wrapper class when testing, like so:

```
// MyApp.spec.js

const sut = require('MyApp');

describe('MyApp', function(){
    describe('process', function(){
        it('should not call save when no data found', async function(){
             // how do I prevent 'new MyWrapper(process.env.username, process.env.password)' from being called???
             // how do I stub "wrapper.getFoo(message.id)" so I can return "undefined"
             const msg = {......};
             const wrapper = new MyWrapper();
             await sut.process(msg, wrapper);
             // now assert wrapper.getFoo was called
             // now assert wrapper.saveFoo was *NOT* called
        });

        ...
});
```

the second part of your question involves creating a stub of a class using sinon. The documentation for sinon, found [here](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v8.1.1/stubs/), is probably going to give you the best example of how to make a stub and return your own value from the stubbed class.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

We probably need to install and include `proxyquire` library to stub `MyWrapper` implementation.

`MyApp.spec.js`

```js
const proxyquire = require("proxyquire"); // include the library here
const sinon = require("sinon");
const chai = require("chai");
const sinonChai = require("sinon-chai");
chai.should();
chai.use(sinonChai);

describe("MyApp", function() {
  describe("process", function() {
    beforeEach(() => {
      sinon.restore(); // best practice to always restore stub
    });

    it("should not call save when no data found", async function() {
      // stub getFoo to return undefined
      const getFooStub = sinon.stub().returns(undefined);
      const saveFooStub = sinon.stub();

      // create wrapper function to return stub
      function MyWrapperStub() {
        return {
          getFoo: getFooStub,
          saveFoo: saveFooStub
        };
      }

      // I don't know why your code use require('MyWrapper'), it should be prefixed with `./`
      // Here is basically we override `./MyWrapper` in our `MyApp.js` with the stub
      const sut = proxyquire("./MyApp", { "./MyWrapper": MyWrapperStub });

      const msg = { id: "123" };
      await sut.process(msg);

      getFooStub.should.have.been.calledWith("123");
      saveFooStub.should.not.have.been.called;
    });

    it("should call save when data is found", async function() {
      // stub getFoo to return json data
      const data = { name: "something" };
      const getFooStub = sinon.stub().returns(data);
      const saveFooStub = sinon.stub();

      function MyWrapperStub() {
        return {
          getFoo: getFooStub,
          saveFoo: saveFooStub
        };
      }
      const sut = proxyquire("./MyApp", { "./MyWrapper": MyWrapperStub });

      const msg = { id: "123" };
      await sut.process(msg);

      getFooStub.should.have.been.calledWith("123");
      saveFooStub.should.have.been.calledWith(data);
    });
  });
});
```

In `MyApp.js`, I changed the implementation of require to be

```js
const MyWrapper = require('./MyWrapper');
```

If you keep insisting to use `require('MyWrapper')` then in the test file, proxyquire must be set to `proxyquire("./MyApp", { "MyWrapper": MyWrapperStub });`

Screenshot:

[image]

Hope it helps

Ref:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire